# How can I add the Flat UI into Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Rails n00b here and I'm just wondering if anyone can help me get the DesignModo Flat UI (free) into the assets pipeline? Do I first have to download and load Bootstrap into the pipeline?

I have found a way to get Bootstrap into rails, which is fairly simple, but I added in the Flat UI files and it just seemed to screw things up. Trying to start over now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this gem

- [flatui-rails](https://github.com/pkurek/flatui-rails) with javascript

Add to your `Gemfile`

`gem 'flatui-rails'`

run `bundle install`

Add to your application.css

`*= require flat-ui`

Add to your application.js

`//= require flat-ui`

---

- [flat-ui-rails](https://github.com/darthdeus/flat-ui-rails) without javascript

add to your `Gemfile`

`gem "flat-ui-rails"`

run `bundle install`

Add flat-ui to your application.css

`*= require flat-ui`

or application.css.scss

`@import "flat-ui";`

Comment: If i have an already existing App with Bootstrap how do i add Flat UI ? just adding the Gems brake the application (Ruby Starter No0b here)

Comment: @TheMiniJohn yes, you could add flat ui gem into your gemfile (`flatui-rails` or `flat-ui-rails`)

Comment: so just under the bootstrap sass gem i add the flatui-rails ?? I think im missing something because my application brakes :(

Comment: @TheMiniJohn I suggestion use [twitter bootstrap rails gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) and flat-ui-rails, what mean application brakes?

Comment: I'm Using gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.0', so u say i just add gem 'faltui-rails' beneath it and it should work ?

Comment: I haven't tried with bootstrap saas gem, `twitter-bootstrap-rails` and `bootstrap-saas` different gem. Tell me, what you mean application brakes? I have tried `flat-ui-rails` gem and `twitter-bootstrap-rails` and it's works

Comment: Sprockets::FileNotFound, couldn't find file 'flat-ui'

Comment: have you run `bundle install` and restart your server?

Comment: Yeap, but still nothing :( If i add the gem to a new rails app, without Bootstrap installed, everything's Perfect. Guess it doesn't work with both installed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34048/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-anonymousxxx)